# How to get versionName/versionCode from kotlin-dsl Gradle file in Gitlab ci script?

Tags: grep, gitlab, yaml, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I get **versionName** and **versionCode** of my android project in Gradle(**Kotlin-DSL**) File from **Gitlab ci script**(gitlab-ci.yaml)?

I have these two commands for getting them from gradle-groovy-dsl, but they don't work on gradle-kotlin-dsl.

```
- export VERSION_NAME=`egrep '^[[:blank:]]+versionName[[:blank:]]'  app/build.gradle | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/\"//g`
- export VERSION_CODE=`egrep '^[[:blank:]]+versionCode[[:blank:]]'  app/build.gradle | awk '{print $2}'`
```

sample gradle script in groovy-dsl:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

sample gradle script in kotlin-dsl:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Read about **Regex**, and i find out how to do it.

you should change the regex to get the versionName/versionCode because the way of assigning them changed.

**you should do it this way:**

```
- export VERSION_NAME=`egrep '[[:blank:]]*versionName[[:blank:]]?=[[:blank:]]?\"((\w|\.)+)\"'  app/build.gradle.kts | awk '{print $3}'| sed s/\"//g`
- export VERSION_CODE=`egrep '[[:blank:]]*versionCode[[:blank:]]?=[[:blank:]]?([0-9]+)'  app/build.gradle.kts | awk '{print $3}'`
```

if you want to learn about regex, i recommend you to see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA) video on youTube